# Windows 8 Upgrade Stuck at Spinning Circles after the First Reboot

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, upgrade, installer

When I try to upgrade my version of Windows from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Pro on my Alienware Aurora R4 with the latest, A07 BIOS, with the Windows upgrade setting to preserve my files and apps, the installation always hangs. More specifically, I start the installation while in Windows 7. It then does its business, and eventually restarts the PC to boot up into the rest of the installation after the BIOS screen, but then it hangs on the Alienware BIOS logo and all I see is the Windows 8 spinner (the white circles that spin around and around, and all they keep doing is spinning for hours on end). I've heard of this working for people if they do not choose the option to keep their files and apps, but I would like to keep mine. I've already gone through all of the Windows upgrade compatibility tests from the compatibility app Microsoft has released and there are no issues with my machine. Does anyone know how I could troubleshoot these problems or what I could do to stop the installation from failing and have it succeed?

Comment: When this happens do you have multiple boot options?  I discovered you have to be sure to allow Windows 8 to fully install which includes a lengthy process, after its done, working within your Windows 7 installation.

Comment: It hangs on the screen with the white spinning circles and when it does this I have no option but to restart the computer at that point in time because they will continue to spin forever. When I restart the computer, I am presented with the boot options of Windows 7, Windows Installation, and Windows 8 - but only going back into Windows 7 and essentially reverting the installation works.

Comment: What happens when you select Windows Installation/Maintenance exactly?  Because I was using a USB optical drive I had to choose the option myself, going into Windows 8, resulted in a crash because it still had 2+ hours of work to do.

Comment: You mean to tell me that the screen with the spinning circles had to keep circulating for over two hours?

Comment: @AAlexandr - There was a spinning circle but there was also a status message.  I didn't sit infront of my computer the entire time.

Comment: Well, the installation will just try to continue the install, but it would still hang on the circles. Like you said, Windows 8 would result in a crash because it hasn't finished the installation process. I never saw a status message though :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6691/discussion-between-ramhound-and-alexandru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. The solution was to install the new Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver!